# Netty NTLM based proxy authorization

Tags: authentication, proxy, netty, ntlm

We have a java standalone process that runs in customer environment. 
The application uses Netty internally and needs to authenticate with the customer's on prem proxy using NTLM.

I know that Netty supports HTTP proxy authentication through its HttpProxyHandler.

Am trying to implement something similar via Netty's proxy handler for NTLM authentication with the proxy. Since Java already supports NTLM authentication which kicks in by defining an authenticator for e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527081/java-https-webservices-connections-through-ntlm-proxy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162996/verifying-ntlmv2-authentication-in-java) can we use the java support when implementing this in Netty or does it work only when using java UrlConnection.

If not would the custom proxyhandler in Netty deal with all the message exchanges ? Thanks !