# soap webservice client using apache cxf, for ntlm authentication

Tags: java, cxf, soap-client, ntlm

I want to develop a SOAP client using CXF to connect to `SharePoint`. The **authentication scheme is NTLM**.

I am blocked on a scenario where the logged-in user of a machine (on which the SOAP client is being run) has access to SharePoint. The CXF soap client always uses the logged-in user. **I want to specify some other user credentials** (not the logged-in).

As CXF uses in-JDK `HttpURLConnection`; and what I have read about `HttpURLConnection` is, it bypasses the specified credentials when the logged-in user is NTLM authenticated.

*Codes were tried on CXF version 2.7.11.*

---

Solutions that I have tried out:

## 1) Setting Conduit authorization

```
String username = "user";     
String password = "password";    

JaxWsProxyfactoryBean factory1 = new JaxWsProxyfactoryBean();    
factory1.setServiceClass(WebsSoap.class);    
factory1.setAddress(url);    
factory1.setUsername(username);    
factory1.setPassword(password);

WebsSoap service = (WebsSoap) factory1.create();    
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(service);    

HTTPconduit conduit = (HTTPconduit) client.getconduit();    
conduit.getAuthorization().setAuthorizationType("NTLM");    
conduit.getAuthorization().setUserName(username);    
conduit.getAuthorization().setPassword(password);

HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();  
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);  
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);  
conduit.setClient(httpClientPolicy);  
        
service.getWeb(".");
```

**Problem:**

This does not work for the scenario specified above, as it always uses the logged-in credentials. And when I specify invalid credentials, it does not fail.

---

## 2) `AsyncHTTPConduit`

Another solution is to use `AsyncHTTPConduit` that uses `HttpAsyncClient` instead of `HttpURLConnection`. This is beacuse HTTP components do not bypass specified credentials and logged-in user can be ignored (I have successfully verified this with a test client using `HttpClient`).

Below is the code snippet::

```
Bus bus = BusFactory.getDefaultBus();    
bus.setProperty( "use.async.http.conduit", "true" );
 
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient( service );    
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();    
if ( http instanceof AsyncHTTPConduit ) {    
    AsyncHTTPConduit conduit = (AsyncHTTPConduit)http;    
    DefaultHttpAsyncClient defaultHttpAsyncClient;    
    try {    
        defaultHttpAsyncClient = conduit.getHttpAsyncClient();    
    }    
    catch ( IOException exception ) {    
        throw new RuntimeException( exception );    
    }    
    defaultHttpAsyncClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( AuthScope.ANY,
                        new NTCredentials( "username", "password", "", "domain" ) );         
    conduit.getClient().setAllowChunking( false );
    conduit.getClient().setAutoRedirect( true );
}
```

**Problem:**

Above code throws error:

> Authorization loop detected on conduit.

The above code snapshot shows the usage of **`DefaultHttpAsyncClient` which is deprecated** now and `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` is to be used instead. But **`CloseableHttpAsyncClient` does not provide a way to specify credentials** to an already existing `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` object. Not sure how to use `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` in this scenario.

---

## 3) Other solutions

The other solution that I tried out is to use `sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthenticationCallback`, to bypass logged-in user authentication, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184881/can-javas-single-sign-on-use-credentials-from-credential-manager-on-windo). Use this approach along with solution #1 mentioned above. This works as expected for valid/invalid credentials, and the code bypasses the logged-in credentials :). But when I specify invalid credentials, I do not get HTTP `401` error, instead I get

> Could not send message, server reached max retries 20

I am trying to avoid this solution because it uses java’s internal package and there is no way to determine HTTP `401` error directly.

What can I do to arrive at a complete solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this interceptor. This will avoid automatic authentication.

```
public class DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>
{
    private boolean isFieldsAvailable;

    private Field tryTransparentNTLMProxyField;

    private Field tryTransparentNTLMServerField;

    public DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);

        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
            public Void run() {
                try {
                    DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor.this.tryTransparentNTLMServerField = HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("tryTransparentNTLMServer");
                    DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor.this.tryTransparentNTLMServerField.setAccessible(true);

                    DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor.this.tryTransparentNTLMProxyField = HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("tryTransparentNTLMProxy");
                    DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor.this.tryTransparentNTLMProxyField.setAccessible(true);
                    DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor.this.isFieldsAvailable = true;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message message) throws Fault {
        if (this.isFieldsAvailable)
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
                public Void run() {
                    try {
                        Object httpConnection = message.get("http.connection");
                        if (httpConnection != null) {
                            DisableAutomaticNTLMAuthOutInterceptor.this.processHttpConnection(message.get("http.connection"));
                        }
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });

    }

    private void processHttpConnection(Object httpConnection) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        if (HttpURLConnection.class.isAssignableFrom(httpConnection.getClass())) {
            tryTransparentNTLMServerField.set(httpConnection, Boolean.FALSE);
            tryTransparentNTLMProxyField.set(httpConnection, Boolean.FALSE);
        } else {
            Field tempField = null;
            for (Field field : httpConnection.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (HttpURLConnection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    tempField = field;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (tempField != null) {
                processHttpConnection(tempField.get(httpConnection));
            }
        }
    }
}
```