# SOAP messages ignore supplied credentials, use Windows login instead

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, soap, jax-ws

I am connecting using webservices from a Java client on Windows to a Sharepoint 2007 server in the same domain. The communication is using `https`.

So far, I checked that by running the client from my account my credentials were used and did not worry more, but now I want to set independent credentials so changes in the items are not logged as "mine", so I put the data in the `requestContext`:

```
Lists listas =
  new Lists(
    new URL(
      urlBase
        + UtilsSp.LISTS_WSDL_PATH),
      new QName(
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/",
        "Lists"));
ListsSoap listasSoap = listas.getListsSoap();
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) listasSoap;
bp.
  getRequestContext().
  put(
    BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
    "MyUser";
  bp.
    getRequestContext().
    put(
      BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
      "MyPassword");
  bp.
    getRequestContext().
    put(
      BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
      "https://mySharepoint.mydomain.com/mySite");
```

But, anyway, I have no errors connecting to the site but the site keeps reporting that I am connecting using my domain username, not the one I pass it through the `requestContext`. What I am missing?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @MateuszBalbus Unfortunately not, I have settled with launching the Java client (which is inside a JBoss) as a windows service running with the credentials needed by the server. Most of what I have seen uses `org.apache.commons.httpclient` or JCIFS, but that offers no way to authenticate through the WSDL generated client; maybe it could be made to work with a proxy, though.

Comment: See below thread for solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184881/can-javas-single-sign-on-use-credentials-from-credential-manager-on-windo